# Neo4j Web Browser : Display phantom data (data does not exists on server)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

We observe unexplainable behaviour with Neo4j Web Browser.

- Cypher query return only 3 relationships but the web browser display 5.
- As you can see, on the right side we have this text : Displaying 4 Nodes, 3 rel
  But the graph shows 5 rel.
- The table Tab in the Web Browser shows 3 records and the cypher results return 3 rel
- We observe this behaviors with other queries, it's not only for the query shared here.
- When we refresh the Neo4j WebBrowser (reload/refresh the chrome browser tab), sometimes we have the display with the right data, sometimes not

[image: a snapshot to help to inderstand]

PS : we run 5.14.0 community version and Neo4j Web Browser 5.12.0

Regards,
Nizar

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56435967/974731

Comment: Note that "streaming 3 records" does NOT mean 3 nodes. A record, in this case, is an entire row, where 1 result row in this case seems to return 1 n node, 1 r rel, and 1 m node. Some of these may overlap, such as all 3 rows having the same n node, but different m nodes, resulting in 4 distinct nodes being displayed (along with all other rels between those nodes provided from the browser's connect result nodes option)

Answer (score 0):

In the neo4j browser, the `connect result nodes` option is enabled by default.

[image]

When you return nodes from queries, the browser will make in the background an additional query for finding relationships between the nodes and automatically display them.

For example, if I would return only two nodes with Cypher

```
MATCH (n:Person {name: "Christophe"})
MATCH (s:Song {title: "Numb"})
RETURN n, s
```

It will find there is an existing relationship between them in the background and will fetch it from the database and display it

[image]

Comment: do you mean I need to disable "connect result nodes" ??
I understand the browser will make in the background an additional query, bah why it display a data (rel in my case) does not existe in the database

Comment: The relationship for sure exist in the database, the browser would not return elements that do not exist in the db

Comment: Okay. So how can you explain what I’m saying in the 5th bullet point ?

Comment: When I refresh a Browser 5.12.0 tab, it reconnects to the server and shows a fresh window without any prior results. How are you refreshing in order to continue to show prior results? Or perhaps you have multiple tabs, some with with older query results, and you are not really refreshing them?

Comment: I have one tab. When I sold refresh I mean I relaod the browser